# How do the Operating System know when a process should be put in the blocked state?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I am studying Operating System. and I know that a process can be turn to blocked state when there are resources currently not available. I wonder, how do the system know if a resources is not available?

see the pseudocode below

```
resource;
resource_availability = False;
while(resource_availability == False){
   resource_availability = get_resource_state();
   if(resource_availability){
      resource = get_resource();
   }
}
```

The while loop will keep running to check if the resource is available or not, there has NO WAITING in this code at all. Then, how do the system know this process need to be blocked?

Comment: ....because it manages them all.  That is what an OS is - a resource manager.

Answer (score 2):

> I wonder, how do the system know if a resources is not available?

Usually, you try to allocate the resource and fail. For an example, it might be like:

```
allocate_resource:
    resource = get_resource();
    if(resource == NULL) {
        do {
            block_task_until_resource_available();
            /* Wait to be unblocked */
            resource = get_resource();
         } while(resource == NULL);
    }
    return resource;
```

..and:

```
deallocate_resource:
    free_resource(resource);
    unblock_tasks_waiting_for_resource();
    return;
```

Of course you'd expect more locking/synchronization; and different pieces of code can be shifted to different locations (e.g. maybe `block_task_until_resource_available();` is built into `get_resource()`).

> The while loop will keep running to check if the resource is available or not, there has NO WAITING in this code at all. Then, how do the system know this process need to be blocked?

Essentially, the code that is used to de-allocate a resource is also responsible for informing the scheduler that the resource is now available (so that the scheduler can unblock any task/s that are blocked waiting for the resource).

The while loop is often there just in case you are unblocked because the resource becomes available but then some other task allocates the resource before you do; or because there can be differences in amounts (e.g. you want 10 things but there were none so you blocked, then someone else gave back 5 things and woke you up, but 5 isn't enough so you still have to wait for more).

Note that in some cases there may be no need for the while loop because a strict "first come first served" order is enforced (e.g. when the resource isn't available you're put on a FIFO queue, and when the resource is deallocated the task that has been waiting the longest is taken from the FIFO queue and unblocked and no other tasks are unblocked). Even in this case you might still have a "hopefully never needed" while loop (good kernel developers use "defensive programming" - there's always a chance that there'll be a bug somewhere that causes "should never happen" to actually happen).

Comment: so you were saying the block happen in the while loop. Each time the `get_resource_state()` is called, the scheduler will block the process if it is not available?

Comment: @YiLuo: Maybe, yes - I updated the answer to provide more info about when a task blocks.